# Не получается создать confirm диалог

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пытаюсь использовать эту библиотеку: https://github.com/aslanon/vue-confirm-dialog Пишу как в примере:

```
this.$confirm({
    message: 'Are you sure?',
    button: {no: 'No', yes: 'Yes'},
    callback (confirm) {
        console.log(confirm)
    }
})
```

Но ничего не происходит. Ни ошибок, ни модалки.

Comment: Показывайте конкретный код (в песочнице какой-нибудь можно). На словах всё что угодно может не работать.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar в смысле конкретный? В посте есть код. Чем он не конкретный?

Comment: Тем, что это просто пример из документации. Очевидно, ошибка не в этом месте. Что вы там делаете на проекте и как подключаете - неизвестно.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar я подключаю все как документации написано. В какой песочнице и что именно вам выложить? Весь код проекта? Просто если бы я что-то не так подключил то очевидно была бы ошибка, но эта функция существует (я проверил отладчиком и даже смог зайти в нее). Просто почему-то при ее вызове ничего не происходит. Может библиотека багнутая?

Comment: А с чего бы она была багнутая? Демка там работает прекрасно. Значит что-то в Вашем коде не так. На кофейной гуще гадать не получится.